# Inaccurate hover info for commitment-phase example questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, area-51

In area 51, looking at the example questions list of a *commitment phase* proposal, hovering over the example question votes displays the text (emphasis mine):

> this example is a great example of a question that would belong on the site **(click again to undo)**

But of course, the proposal is already in the commitment phase so votes cannot be cast, and the vote boxes cannot be clicked. Maybe it should change to something like:

> This is the amount of people who voted this question as a great example of questions that would belong on the site

And similarly for off-topic / bad examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commitment-phase tooltips have been fixed. Thanks @Oak.

Answer (score 0):

While inaccurate, this seems to be the normal tool tip behavior on all of the sites. For instance, votes you cast on SO a year ago will still say "Click again to undo" even though the time you could have done so has long since passed.